# WebdriverIO tests are being skipped

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

When I start to run my tests from the terminal, I notice my tests are being skipped. There is no error message displaying for this issue. I also didn't include a skip (it.skip) in my test.

[Terminal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxhMi.png)

[wdio.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQMT6.png)

I have confirmed no skips in the test (it.skip). I expect for the tests not to be skipped.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We need a [mre], in the question, **as text**.